# Update Google Sheet through API without dataframe headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, formatting

This is my function for updating my Google Sheet with new data:

```
response_data = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
                spreadsheetId = SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID_input,
                valueInputOption = 'RAW',
                range = SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,
                insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
                body = dict(
                    majorDimension = 'ROWS',
                    values = df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
            ).execute()
            print('Sheet successfully Updated')
```

I run this everyday, and so I have no need to re-write the headers everyday. Simply writing the new data from the new day is sufficient (date is one of the items in each entry).

How can I strip the headers from the dataframe before writing to Google Sheets?

Comment: What about just `df.values.tolist()` in place of `df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I started getting strange behavior with some date times (I was using USER_ENTERED) once I made this change, but I fixed that by prepending a '. Thanks again